# Setting date range in queries

Tags: sql, clojure

I would like to add a condition in my query to filter records which has a date falling under current month. How can I achieve this? I tried to use clj-time to retrieve the current month and match it along with the DB field. But that didn't give me any luck.

Comment: Please give more details regarding what database you are using, your current code, SQL DSL (if you are using one), etc.

Comment: I'm using kormasql for database related functions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's pretty simple to determine the current month using `clj-time`:

```
(month (now)) ; number from 1 to 12
```

But, since you're trying to query a database, you should be interested with the beginning of the current month:

```
(let [t (now)]
  (date-time (year t) (month t)))
```

This code will return you a valid `DateTime` object, corresponding to the beginning of the current month. You can use this object t query your SQL database:

```
(select objects
  (where {:created [> start_of_the_current_month]}))
```